# Tricky approach of parsing an object with 2 properties to 2 separate models in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have this code

```
<input ng-model="attribute.name" typeahead="property as property.name for property in MyObject | filter:{ paramName:$viewValue }">
```

MyObject is

```
{ name : 'A',
  desc : 'A description'
}
```

attribute.name need to stay as a simple string. However, with the code above, attribute.name becomes an object which I don't want. So I changed the code to

```
<input ng-model="attribute.name" typeahead="property.name as property.name for property in MyObject | filter:{ paramName:$viewValue }">
```

Everything is working great until I also needed to render "desc" key. It doesn't have to be in ng-model but as long as I can render it, that would be nice. I don't need two way binding for "desc" because I want the data to be editable in free form.

Now that I'm only returning property.name which is not an object anymore, how do I access "desc" key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the last example on the `typeahead` page: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead.

I'll need to:

1 - Change you expression to let the object complete but selecting only the property you want. Also, using the `ngModel.$viewValue` to provide the string to filter. So:

```
<input ng-model="attribute.name"
    typeahead="property as property.name for property in MyObject | filter:{name: $viewValue}">
```

2 - Define a template to show the results. You need to setup a pattern in this template, following the rules to show the results correctly. One example for it is:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="resultPattern.html">
    <div>
        <span ng-bind="match.name | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span><br>
        <small ng-bind="match.desc"></small>
    </div>
</script>
```

3 - The final `input` tag will be:

```
<input ng-model="attribute.name"
    typeahead="property as property.name for property in MyObject | filter:{name: $viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="resultPattern.html">
```

## Edit 1:

You were right, i've mistyped on the step 3:

```
<input ng-model="attribute.name"
    typeahead="property.name as property for property in MyObject | filter:{name: $viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="resultPattern.html">
```

Here is a Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/pcjV40KxkBFdyIM3L0M4?p=preview

## Edit 2:

I've updated the Plunkr with a callback function used to deal with the selection after it: http://plnkr.co/edit/pcjV40KxkBFdyIM3L0M4?p=preview

Also, there's a formatter for the `ngModel`, that you can use to choose which item to display after the selection, letting to the same `ngModel` the entire information.

Comment: The problem with your code on number 3(same as my topmost code) is that the attribute.name model will be populated with an object and not with a string. On the browser page, it will display the name value but in the $scope.attribute.name, it is an object containing name and desc. So why does it only show the name on the webpage? It only shows the name value because of the filter. I explained above on my post why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm so sorry, maybe my post was confusing and incomplete. I don't have any issue displaying the suggestions/typeahed. I'll update my post. The issue I have is that after I clicked a choice, I am unable to assign the value of "desc" to another model.  I'm actually thinking of reverting back to my old code(topmost code) and then right before I do a $htttp.post, I'll clean the data so that it removes the object and just use the value of "name".

Comment: I was thinking that you want a solution to select the `name` and show the `desc` on the `typeahead` box... I've done that on the Plunkr. You need to get the `desc` and use it on your code too?

Comment: Yes, the desc will be displayed on another part of the webpage.

Comment: Look at the new `Edit 2` on the answer, I guess that is what you need =)

Comment: That is really nice! I also tried the solution I mentioned on my last post and it worked! However, your solution is nicer :)